# Unique solution in linear optimisation problem

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, lagrange-multiplier, convex-geometry, non-convex-optimization

Consider the following linear programming problem
$$
\min_{x}\sum_{j=1}^J x_ja_j\\
s.t.\\
x_j\geq 0 \text{ }\forall j=1,...,J\\
\sum_{j=1}^J x_jb_{j,r}-c_r=0 \text{ }\forall r=1,...,R
$$
where $a_j, b_{j,r}, c_r$ are known scalars $\forall j=1,...,J$ and $\forall r=1,...,R$. $x$ is a $J\times 1$ vector.

Consider the Lagrangian
$$
\mathcal{L}(x,\mu_1,...,\mu_R,\tau_1,...,\tau_J)\equiv \sum_{j=1}^J x_ja_j+\sum_{r=1}^R \mu_r(\sum_{j=1}^J x_jb_{j,r}-c_r)+\sum_{j=1}^J \tau_j x_j
$$

**Question:** I'm looking for a way to "perturb" $\mathcal{L}(x,\mu_1,...,\mu_R,\tau_1,...,\tau_J)$ such that the Lagrangian multipliers $\mu_1,...,\mu_R$ are unique and that does not modify "too much" the solution of the original problem.

I'm asking this because the the Lagrangian multipliers $\mu_1,...,\mu_R$ determine another piece of my problem which would be enormously simplified if the Lagrangian multipliers $\mu_1,...,\mu_R$ are unique (too long to explain in details).

I understand that my question is very sloppy, I'm not a mathematician, your comments would be very appreciated also to help me reformulate my question in appropriate terms.

Comment: What is the mean of ``unique''? Do you mean that the solution of Lagrangian multiplier, i.e., $\mu_r^*=\arg\max_{\mu^r} \mathcal{L}$, should be unique?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can add a proximal term for Lagrangian multiplier. More details you can refer to Augmented Lagrangian Method.

Comment: Thanks, I gave a look: ALM seems a method to solve constrained optimisation problems. How does it relate to uniqueness of solution for lagrangian multipliers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primal problem is
$$\min_x\left\{a^Tx : B^Tx = c, x\geq 0\right\}$$
The dual problem is:
$$\max_y \left\{c^Ty : By \leq a\right\}$$
To ensure that the dual has a unique solution, you could modify the dual into:
$$\max_y \left\{c^Ty + \rho ||y||_2 : By \leq a\right\}$$
with $\rho>0$. The corresponding primal is:
$$\min_x\left\{a^Tx : ||B^Tx-c||_2 \leq \rho, x\geq 0\right\}$$
If you pick $\rho$ sufficiently small, the optimal value will not change too much.

Comment: Thanks. The solution to the dual is the vector of lagrangian multipliers, correct?

Comment: Also, is there any name/reference for the method you suggest?

Comment: @STF 1. You need to use the constraints $z=c-B^Tx$ and $||z||_2 \leq \rho$ to get the dual solution as lagrange multiplier of the equality constraint (otherwise the lagrange multiplier is just a scalar). 2. I do not know of a name, but it is well known that a strictly convex function has a unique minimizer on a convex set (when a minimum exists).

Comment: Thanks, it would be very helpful if you could write how to get exactly the $\mu$'s from the problem. Thanks

Comment: @STF many optimization algorithms can output the lagrange multipliers. Otherwise, you need to numerically obtain them from the KKT conditions, which is harder.

Comment: Thanks. Uniqueness of solution of the dual ensures uniqueness of solution of $\mu$?

Comment: yes, because the dual solution is $\mu$