# Strictly convex dual problem

Tags: linear-algebra, duality-theorems

Consider the following **primal** problem:
$$
(1) \quad \max_{y} c^\top y ,\\
\quad \quad \quad \text{s.t. } By \leq a
$$
The **dual** of (1) is
$$
(2) \quad \min_{x\geq 0} a^\top x,\\
\quad \quad \quad \text{s.t. }B^\top x=c
$$

Consider the Lagrangian of (2):
$$
L(x,\mu,v)=a^\top x-\nu^\top x+\mu^\top(B^\top x-c)
$$

Consider the sets of $x$ and $\mu$ satisfying the KKT conditions of (2). Let me call these sets $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{M}$ respectively. **I want to perturb (2) so as to ensure that $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{M}$ are singleton**. Following this suggestion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3618883/unique-solution-in-linear-optimisation-problem), I replace (2) with

$$
(3) \quad \min_{x\geq 0} a^\top x+ \epsilon ||x||_2,\\
\quad \quad \quad \text{s.t. }B^\top x=c
$$
with $\epsilon>0$. If $\epsilon$ is small enough, then (3) $\approx $ (2).

**Questions:**

- Are $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{M}$ of (3) singleton, as desired?
- What is the **primal** that has (3) as dual?

Comment: Does (3) satisfy the LICQ? Why do you want the solution to be unique?

Comment: I need $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{M}$ to be singleton because they enter another part of my broader original problem which simplifies substantially if $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{M}$ are singleton.

Comment: (3) does not satisfy the LICQ, I believe. But, looking at your answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4084561/strictly-convex-linear-programming-linear-independence-constraint-qualification, I believe that the primal of (3) should satify the LICQ, but I'm not sure how to write the primal of (3).

Comment: Enter how? If there are multiple solutions, why not pick the one with minimum norm?

Comment: Inside my problem, at a certain step, I have to compute a quantity that is $\min_{x\in \mathcal{X}} \max_{\mu\in \mathcal{M}} f(\mu,x)$, where $f(\mu,x)$ is a very complicated function. If $\mathcal{X}\equiv \{x^*\}$ and $\mathcal{M}\equiv \{\mu^*\}$, then I can just replace $f(\mu^*,x^*)$. I want to "slightly" perturb my original problem so that $f(\mu^*,x^*)$ should be "almost" correct.

Comment: Can't you redefine $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{M}$ to be minimum norm solutions to (1) and (2)? Unless, (3) satisfies the LICQ, its primal will not have a unique solution.

Comment: I think I'm not being clear, apologies. I don't care about the primal (1) having a unique solution. I want the dual (2) to have unique solutions wrto $(x,\mu)$. To make this happening, I perturb the dual (2) as described in (3). My questions are: does (3) have a unique solution wrto $(x,\mu)$? What is the primal problem that has (3) as dual?

Comment: (3) has a unique solution wrto $x$ but not to $\mu$ (unless (3) satisfies the LICQ).

Comment: Thanks. This is very useful and answers my first question. Could you also help me to write down what is the primal problem that has (3) as dual?

Comment: @LinAlg Not necessarily. It depends (among other things) on $\|a\|$, if $\|a\| \ge \epsilon$ there are some directions in which it is flat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider
$$
\min_{x\geq 0} a^\top x+ \epsilon_1 ||x||_2,\\
\quad \text{s.t. } ||B^\top x-c||_2 \leq \epsilon_2
$$

The Lagrange dual is
\begin{align}
& \max_{\lambda\geq 0,\nu \geq 0} \min_{x} a^\top x+ \epsilon_1 ||x||_2 + \lambda(||B^\top x-c||_2 - \epsilon_2) - \nu^Tx \\
= \; & \max_{\lambda\geq 0,\nu \geq 0} \min_{x,z} \max_{y} a^\top x+ \epsilon_1 ||x||_2 + \lambda(||z||_2 - \epsilon_2) - \nu^Tx + y^T(z+c-B^\top x) \\
= \; & \max_{y,\lambda\geq 0,\nu \geq 0} \min_{x,z} (a-By-\nu)^T x+ \epsilon_1 ||x||_2 + y^Tz + \lambda||z||_2  + c^Ty - \lambda\epsilon_2 \\
= \; & \max_{y,\lambda\geq 0,\nu \geq 0} \left\{ c^Ty - \lambda\epsilon_2 : ||By-a+\nu||\leq\epsilon_1, ||y||_2 \leq \lambda \right\} \\
\end{align}
To express the dual we needed an extra variable $y$ which is not necessarily unique, but the dual variable $\lambda$ is unique because the corresponding constraint in the primal ($||B^\top x-c||_2 \leq \epsilon_2$) satisfies the LICQ. I am therefore not sure if this is helpful, because you still have the 'same' $y$ you started with.

Either way, by taking $\epsilon_2=0$ you obtain the dual to (3):
$$\max_{y,\nu \geq 0} \left\{ c^Ty : ||By-a+\nu||\leq\epsilon \right\}.$$

Comment: Thanks. Is $\epsilon_2$ to ensure that LICQ applies, so that the problem has a unique solution wrto $x$ AND $\mu$?

Comment: $\epsilon_2$ is used to turn multiple linear constraints into a single nonlinear constraint

Comment: You are telling me that $$\max_{y,\nu\geq 0} c^\top y \text{ s.t. } ||By-a+\nu|| \leq \epsilon$$ is the DUAL of (3). But I want the PRIMAL of (3).

Comment: @TEX the dual of the dual is the primal

Comment: OK, therefore $$\max_{y,\nu\geq 0} c^\top y \text{ s.t. } ||By-a+\nu|| \leq \epsilon$$ is the PRIMAL of (3)?

Comment: if (3) is the dual, then yes, that is the primal

Comment: I still have 2 doubts. Could you confirm if the following holds: (i) if I impose LICQ on (3), then (3) HAS unique solution wrto $x,\mu$. (ii) if I impose LICQ on (2), then (2) DOES NOT NECESSARILY HAVE unique solution wrto $x,\mu$.

Comment: @TEX yes to both

Comment: Thanks, I need to show (i). I'll ask it in another question.

Comment: I was looking again at your answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3618883/unique-solution-in-linear-optimisation-problem. In the above answer, you suggest as dual of (3) $$\max_{y,\nu\geq 0} c^\top y \text{ s.t. } ||By-a+\nu||\geq \epsilon $$ Instead, if I look at the old answer, it seems that the dual of (3) should be $$\max_{y} c^\top y \text{ s.t. } ||By-a|| \leq \epsilon$$ without adding $\nu$. Which one is correct?

Comment: @TEX they are both correct, (3) is not the same as the problem in the linked question (equality vs inequality constraints). If you modify $B$ in the linked question to accommodate for slacks, you get the same dual as here.